# Expressing components of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you have a block matrix of $n \times n$ matrices $M = \begin{pmatrix} A&B\\ C&D \end{pmatrix}$
and you know rank ($A$) = rank($M$) = $n$. Show that $D= CA^{-1}B$. I'm really confused as to how to show this. Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically part of the proof for the determinant formula based on [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). Observe that
$$
\underbrace{\pmatrix{I&0\\ -CA^{-1}&I}}_X
\underbrace{\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}}_M
=\underbrace{\pmatrix{A&B\\ 0&D-CA^{-1}B}}_Y.
$$
As $X$ is invertible, the matrices $M$ and $Y$ have identical ranks. Now you may try to argue that $D-CA^{-1}B=0$ by inspecting the row rank of $Y$.